# hardware volume+- button bug on Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (P7510), it can not trigger onKeyDown event when system volume bar is appeared

Tags: android, galaxy-tab

My app runs OK on each other android phone but Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (P7510) with android 3.1/3.2.

When pressing hardware volume+/volume- button first time, API onKeyDown with KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN/KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP is triggered well(system volume bar is appeared). But pressing hardware volume+/volume- button again, onKeyDown() will not be triggered until system volume bar is disappeared.

I need process someting when the user presses volume+/volume- each time but can not capture onKeyDown.....

The problem only occurs on Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (P7510) and Moto XOOM. Is it a android 3.x problem？

Other devices which runs android 2.x or 4.x are OK.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override `dispatchKeyEvent` method instead `onKeyDown`. In all cases, when you process the event, return `true`. In other cases return `super.dispatchKeyEvent`.